# Trying to upload/openeing files from/to firebase storage

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, file-upload, firebase-storage

React Native app. What i am doing is uploading a file wether it is a picture or a pdf. My problem is i cant seem to open the files once uploaded. "The files are getting uploaded to the storage".

```
export const uploadToStorage = async (document: any) => {
  try {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const fileName = document?.name;

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${fileName}`);
    
    const fileRef = ref(storageRef);
    const fileType = document?.mimeType;
    const metaData = {
      contentType: fileType
    };
    const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, document, metaData);
    console.log('Upload successful:', snapshot);

    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);
    console.log('Download URL:', downloadURL);
    return downloadURL;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

```
 const _pickDocument = async () => {
    const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
      multiple: false,
    })
    if (result !== null) {
      result.assets?.map(async (item: any) => {
        const filePrefix = 'file://'
        if (item.uri.startsWith(filePrefix)) {
          item.uri = item.uri.substring(filePrefix.length)
        }
        console.log('URL:' + item.mimeType)
        dispatch(addPDF(item.name))
        if (auth.currentUser?.uid !== null) {
          console.log(auth.currentUser?.uid)
          
          await uploadToStorage(item).then((downloadUrl) => {
            setDownloadUrl(downloadUrl)
            
          }) 
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Allow read and write access to all files
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to send different headers/metaData and it did not make a change. I tried uploadBytes instead of uploadBytesResumable and the same thing.

The file is getting uploaded correctly but i cant open it manually from firbase storage.

If i upload for example a pdf i get Error:Failed to load PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

According to its documentation [`uploadBytesResumable`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#uploadbytesresumable_02686b1) takes a `Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer` for its data. As far as I can see, your `item`/`document` is a [`DocumentPickerAsset`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/#documentpickerasset), which is not an accepted type.

You'll want to [read the bytes](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/#documentpickerasset) from the `File` in the asset, and pass *those* to Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still the file does not open 
"""const response = await fetch(item.uri);
const fileArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const fileBytes = new Uint8Array(fileArrayBuffer);  
await uploadToStorage(fileBytes)
"""
"""
export const uploadToStorage = async (bytes: Uint8Array) => {
 try {
   const storage = getStorage();
   const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/test`);
   const metaData = {
   contentType: 'application/pdf'
    };

  const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, bytes, metaData);
  console.log('Upload successful:', snapshot);
"""

Comment: Indeed the size of the file is bigger